# JSON string not parsing header part of the string

Tags: java, json

Json string :

```
{
    "event": {
        "event_name": "Customer Phone Number",
        "operation_type": "Add",
        "transaction_identifier": "1234567890",
        "event_publication_timestamp_millis": "1518464452915",
        "event_publisher": "CIS",
        "event_publisher_identity": "System",
        "event_timestamp_millis": "NONE",
        "event_initiator": "NONE",
        "event_initiator_identity": "NONE"
    },
    "contents": [
        {
            "data_group_name": "customer_identifier",
            "data_fields": [
                {
                    "data_field_name": "company_number",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "069"
                },
                {
                    "data_field_name": "customer_short_name",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "marshben"
                },
                {
                    "data_field_name": "tie_breaker",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "01"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "data_group_name": "customer_phone_number",
            "data_fields": [
                {
                    "data_field_name": "phone_number",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "555-1212"
                },
                {
                    "data_field_name": "phone_type",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "cell"
                },
                {
                    "data_field_name": "primary_indicator",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "yes"
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}

JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(result);

        System.out.println("this");

        System.out.println(rootObject.toString());
```

The above code only gives contents part of it, how to get the top level data which starts with event.

```
Here is the output of :

    "contents": [
        {
            "data_group_name": "customer_identifier",
            "data_fields": [
                {
                    "data_field_name": "company_number",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "069"
                },
                {
                    "data_field_name": "customer_short_name",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "marshben"
                },
                {
                    "data_field_name": "tie_breaker",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "01"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "data_group_name": "customer_phone_number",
            "data_fields": [
                {
                    "data_field_name": "phone_number",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "555-1212"
                },
                {
                    "data_field_name": "phone_type",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "cell"
                },
                {
                    "data_field_name": "primary_indicator",
                    "data_field_type": "string",
                    "data_field_value": "yes"
                }
            ]
        }

    ]
}
```

I would like to parse every element and read the values. But the json object is parsing only part of the string. what is the bestway to process this string.
The top level part which starts with event is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example, you shared I can see all the elements are in the rootObject variable. It's just that the ordering has changed.

Your Input JSON had a structure like this

```
{
 "event": {..},
 "contents": [..]
}
```

And when creating and outputing the JSON object it becomes something like this:

```
{
 "contents": [..],
 "event": {..}
}
```

Meaning all fields are in the JSONObject but only the order has changed and this is expected as it is not necessary to maintain the order of fields as per the JSON spec. You could verify that the fields are indeed present by parsing by field name. For the above example:

```
System.out.println(rootObject.get("event").toString());
```

Comment: Awesome harish, , now how i can get the values,

Doing like this, in the code

 
  
  JSONObject rootObject = new JSONObject(result);
  
  JSONObject objc = (JSONObject) rootObject.get("event");

How to convert this to an array and get all the elements

Comment: 'event' is not an array, 'contents' is. Just check the bracket type followed by the field name. If its `[` then it is an array and if its `{` its an object. You can parse an array using the JSONArray like this `final JSONArray contentsArray = rootObject.getJSONArray("contents");         final JSONObject firsContent = (JSONObject) contentsArray.get(0);`

Comment: Excellent Harish, It worked like a charm, thank you very much, you are the best